# change or interpret class encoding of dummy variable in PROC GLMSELECT

Tags: sas

I am using this simplified example to fit some regression model using PROC GLMSELECT in SAS:

```
PROC GLMSELECT DATA = WORK.Bla1 TESTDATA = WORK.Bla2;
    class catvar;
    MODEL
        y = 
        x
        catvar / selection = none stb showpvalues;
RUN;
```

The categorical variable catvar has 3 values a, b and c. After fitting the model:

```
catvar = c
```

always has the estimate 0 and a missing p value. I think this has to do with the fact that the above uses the standard 'REF encoding' which does this (see [here](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_glmselect_sect020.htm)):

```
catvar = a => 1 0
catvar = b => 0 1
catvar = c => 0 0
```

catvar = c is the reference level. Can I prevent this behaviour to get an estimate and p value for every value of catvar? If not, how do I interpret catvar = c? Any feedback would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The default is not REF but GLM. Your output should show you the design matrix used. This is a matter of interpretation more than getting an actual estimate. By design you don't get estimates since everything is in relation to a base level. This isn't a SAS question, it's a statistical question and should be in cross validated instead. Here's a better write up of the different ways of categorizing your variables. http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/webbooks/reg/chapter5/sasreg5.htm

Comment: @Reeza - thanks I know this is more a statistics question but I was wondering about the SAS specifics.